# Ajax Posting via jQuery to custom controller method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I'm having an issue posting data to my custom controller methods via a jquery ajax post.

I have the following rails myPlayer.erb.html:

```
<% form_for @playersonline, :url =>  game_index_path, :html => { :method => :put, :class => "block", :id => "playersOnline_form" } do |f| %>

        <% @playersonline.each do |member| %>

          <li>
            <div class="playerDetails">
              <div class="playerNickname"><%= member.nickname %></div>
              <div class="playerPlayLink">
                <input type="button" class="submit_button playPlayer" id="<%= member.nickname %>" value="Play" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

        <% end %>

        <p class="morePlayers">  
          <a href="">View more players >></a>
        </p>

      <% end %>
```

The forms html looks like this when rendered:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/game" class="block" id="playersOnline_form" method="post">
```

And the following jQuery code that attaches event handllers to each button.

```
SITE.Game = function() {

  $('.playPlayer').live('click', 
    function() { 
      SITE.Game.sendGameRequest() 
    } 
  );
}

SITE.Game.sendGameRequest = function() {

  $.post('/game/test,{"testData": "One", "testDataAgain": "Two"}, function(result) { console.log("data returned = " + result); }, "json")

}
```

So when I click a button, and the event fires making the ajax request I get the following error back:

```
Started POST "/game/test" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-13 00:05:59 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/game/test"):
```

My controller looks like this, and I can see from the server output that its not going into my test method:

```
class GameController < ApplicationController

  def test
    puts "---------------------------"
    puts "GAME TEST WORKING"
    puts "---------------------------"  
  end

  def index  

    @returnMember = ["Tom","Pete"]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @returnMember.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

I have the following in my routes also:

```
resources :game
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

### EDIT

In response to nzifnab reply. I added:

```
resource :game do
  member do
    post 'test'
  end
end
```

But am now getting:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant GamesController):
```

### EDIT 2

Fixed above by changing controller to GamesControllor from GameController.

Now getting the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `games_index_path'
    <% form_for @playersonline, :url =>  games_index_path, :html => { :method => :put, :class => "block", :id => "playersOnline_form" } do |f| %

>
```

See my controller at beginning of issue.

### EDIT 3

Fix for Edit 2 is quite simple! Changed url to games_path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resources :game` sets up a RESTful route for your controller which automatically enables the `show`, `create`, `new`, `edit`, `update`, and `destroy` actions.  If you want it to hit the `test` action you need to do this in your routes file:

```
resource :game do
  member do
    post :test
  end
end
```

Or if you don't need all of those other RESTful routes you can do this:

```
match 'game/test' => 'game#test'
```

That's for rails 3.  In rails 2.3.x the resourceful way would be like this:

```
resource :game, :members => {:test => :post}
```

I believe

Rails also expects your controllers to be named in the plural format.  So a file in `controllers/games_controller.rb` should have the `class GamesController < ApplicationController` as it's class contents.

I would juse rename the file and/or controller to match the convention.  But if you *really* need to keep it named singular for some reason you can add this to your routes file:

resource :game, :controller => 'game' do
  # Other stuff here
end

I think that would fix it.  But it's more usual for people to just pluralize their controller names.

Comment: Ok I tried that and got a little further, its actually post 'test' also :). Now I'm getting this error: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant GamesController): .... Any ideas?

Comment: @Mcloving Updated my answer, see the text after 'I believe'

Comment: Yep, guessed that before checking back here :) Thanks nzifnab. I have yet another issue now. Would be grateful if you could help. If you feel its unrelated I'll create a new issue. See the end of my original answer for latest issue.

Comment: Got answer to that too! See my original question for it. Thanks for all your help nzifab.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your data type. It depends what kinda datatype you want but this is how you could do html and json:

JSON example:

```
 SITE.Game.sendGameRequest = function() {
  $.post('/game/test.json,{"testData": "One", "testDataAgain": "Two"}, function(result) {
     console.log("data returned = " + result); }, "json")
}
```

And HTML:

SITE.Game.sendGameRequest = function() {

```
  $.post('/game/test.html,{"testData": "One", "testDataAgain": "Two"}, function(result) { console.log("data returned = " + result); }, "html")

}
```

then in your controller you need to check the format:

```
class GameController < ApplicationController
  def test
      responds_to |format|
          format.html #need for ajax with html datatype 
          format.json #need for ajax with json datatype
      end
  end
end
```

Change log:

```
[changed] the paths for your ajax request
[added] responds_to helper in your controller
```

And don't forget to declare the route in your routes.rb:

```
 map.resources :games
```